# Infinite real series diverging to $+ \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, divergent-series

If a series diverges to $+\infty$ Does it imply sequence from which series comes also diverges to $+\infty$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. There are simple counterexamples:

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} 1 = +\infty $$

The underlying sequence can even converge to zero! Usually the first example one is taught is the Harmonic series

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{n} = +\infty $$